# scanner doesnt work in if statement

Tags: java, if-statement

** OK, So I'm trying to create a Russian Roulette Game. Half this code is supposed to play one way and the other another way (if that makes sense). Anyways I made them on two separate classes and then combined them. My problem is now every time I try to create an if statement to decide which way to play it doesn't work. I guess, I would just like some help or hints as to why this is. Like could someone point me in the right direction? (I deleted my attempts at the if statement, should I put them back?)

P.S I'm a noob to this stuff. I really don't understand. And I'm pretty sure my OddsEvenChoice if statement is incorrect but I'll worry about that later.**

```
package game;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class RouletteTester {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner scanner = new Scanner (System.in);
        int Mode;

        System.out.println("Please choose how you'd like to play.");
        System.out.println("To play by Odds & Evens, enter '1'");
        System.out.println("To play by Numbers, enter '2'");
        System.out.println("Enter game mode here: ");

        Mode = scanner.nextInt();

        System.out.println("You chose game mode " + Mode);

        Scanner in = new Scanner (System.in);
        System.out.print("Enter roulette number here: ");
        int Number = in.nextInt();

        RouletteWheel One = new RouletteWheel();

        One.spin();
        int r = One.getwinningNumber();

        System.out.println(r);

        if (r == Number)
            System.out.println("Congratulations, The" + Number + " is a winning number!");
        else                
            System.out.println("Sorry, " + Number + " is not a winning number.");

        if (r == 0)
            System.out.println("Congratulations, 0 is an automatic win!");

        Scanner inn = new Scanner (System.in);  
        System.out.println("Odds or Evens? Type '1' for odds"
                + " or '2' for evens: "); 
        int Numberr = inn.nextInt(); 

        if (Numberr == 1)
            System.out.println("You choose Odds.");
        else 
            System.out.println("You choose Evens.");

        One.spin();
        int winningNumber = One.getwinningNumber();
        boolean n = One.OddEvenChoice();
        System.out.println("The wheel landed on...");
        System.out.println(winningNumber);

        if ((n == true) && (winningNumber % 2 == 0))
            System.out.println("You Win! E");
        else if ((n == false) && (winningNumber %2 == 1))
            System.out.println("You Win! O");
        else 
            System.out.println("You Lose.");
    }
}
```

Comment: you be more specific about where the problems are happening in the code, thank you (you can edit your post to clarify)

Answer (score 1):

There is no need to use multiple instances of Scanner. Instantiate it only once as you did in the beginning : `Scanner scanner = new Scanner (System.in);` and just reuse it every time you need it.

This is an example based on your code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {


        Scanner scanner = new Scanner (System.in);
        int Mode;

        System.out.println("Please choose how you'd like to play.");
        System.out.println("To play by Odds & Evens, enter '1'");
        System.out.println("To play by Numbers, enter '2'");
        System.out.println("Enter game mode here: ");

        Mode = scanner.nextInt();

        System.out.println("You chose game mode " + Mode);

        System.out.print("Enter roulette number here: ");
        int Number = scanner.nextInt();

        RouletteWheel One = new RouletteWheel();

        One.spin();
        int r = One.getWinningNumber();

        System.out.println(r);

        if (r == Number)
            System.out.println("Congratulations, The" + Number + " is a winning number!");
        else                
            System.out.println("Sorry, " + Number + " is not a winning number.");

        if (r == 0)
            System.out.println("Congratulations, 0 is an automatic win!");


        System.out.println("Odds or Evens? Type '1' for odds"
                + " or '2' for evens: "); 
        int Numberr = scanner.nextInt(); 

        if (Numberr == 1)
            System.out.println("You choose Odds.");
        else 
            System.out.println("You choose Evens.");


        One.spin();
        int winningNumber = One.getWinningNumber();
        boolean n = One.OddEvenChoice();
        System.out.println("The wheel landed on...");
        System.out.println(winningNumber);


        if ((n == true) && (winningNumber % 2 == 0))
            System.out.println("You Win! E");
        else if ((n == false) && (winningNumber %2 == 1))
            System.out.println("You Win! O");
        else 
            System.out.println("You Lose.");
    }
```

And it works:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I suspect your problem is that you have multiple scanners on the same stream (scanner and inn both read from System.in) I think the first scanner will consume all of the input, and nothing will make it to the second, it might not be that simple though.

Get rid of inn, and use scanner the whole time, and that might fix it.

Comment: So I tried that, it was unsuccessful. It could just be me though. When I put the two modes into if statements the scanners are the only lines with errors.

Comment: Wait, I'm a dummy. So this time I correctly changed all the scanners & got rid of the extra 2 ( Scanner in = new Scanner (System.in); ) lines. There are no errors so I guess that's good. Now I just have to get this thing to properly choose the game mode. Thanks!